# Necessary and sufficient condition for weak convergence and convergence of density

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $(\mu_n)_n$ and $\mu$ be two probability measure, having respectively density $(f_n)_n$ and $f$ for the measure $\lambda$ on $(\mathbb{R},B(\mathbb{R})).$

1. Prove that the following statement are equivalent:

   a) $(\mu_n)_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$ and $$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0;\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall E \in B(\mathbb{R}),\lambda(E)\leq \delta\implies\int_Ef_n(x)dx \leq \epsilon$$
   b) $(\mu_n)_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$ and $$\lim_{k\to+\infty}\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\int_{\left\{f_n>k \right\}}f_n(x)dx=0.$$

   c) $\forall E \in B(\mathbb{R}),\lim_{n\to+\infty}\mu_n(E)=\mu(E).$
2. If $(\mu_n)_n$ converges weakly to a probability measure $\sigma$ and for all $\epsilon>0,$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N},$ for all $E \in B(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\lambda(E)\leq \delta,\int_Ef_n(x)dx \leq \epsilon.$ Is it true that $\sigma$ have a probability density ? (There exist $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^+,$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)dx=1, \sigma(U)=\int_U\phi(x)dx,$ for all $U \in B(\mathbb{R})$)

This is the attempt so far.

a) $\implies$ b). Take $\epsilon>0.$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\forall E \in B(\mathbb{R}),\lambda(E) \leq \delta \implies \int_Ef_ndx \leq \epsilon.$$ Let $k \geq \frac{1}{\delta}.$ So $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\lambda(\left\{f_n>k \right\}) \leq \frac{1}{k} \leq \delta$$ which means that $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\int_{\left\{f_n>k \right\}}f_n \leq\epsilon,$$ Then $\sup_n\int_{\left\{f_n>k \right\}}f_n(x)dx \leq \epsilon.$

b) $\implies$ a). Let $\epsilon>0.$ there exist $k>0$ such that $$\sup_n \int_{\left\{f_n>k \right\}}f_n(x)dx \leq \epsilon/2.$$
Let $n \in \mathbb{N},E \in B(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\lambda(E) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2(k+1)}.$
$$\int_E f_n(x)dx \leq k\lambda(E)+\int_{\left\{f_n>k \right\}}f_n(x)dx \leq \epsilon.$$

How can we proceed with c) $\implies$ a)? 2) is the statement correct?

Comment: Which definition of weak convergence are you using?

Comment: Also, are there some of the 6 possible directions in your first problem that you have already tried to solve?

Comment: weak convergence of probability measure: for all bounded and continuous function $f$: $\lim_n\int_Rf(x)d\mu_n(x)=\int_Rf(x)d\mu,$ we can find equivalent statement, portmanteau theorem

Comment: @Kurt.W.X "c) => a)" from Vitali-Hahn-Saks Theorem,  cf.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali-Hahn-Saks_theorem .
"2. is true" from Dunford-Pettis theorem, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability.

Comment: To apply Vitali-Hahn-Saks Theorem, the measure $\lambda$ should be finite, right? unless if the theorem is also true for $\sigma$-finite measure..

Comment: The 2 theorems, they are another approach to solve the problem, right? More precisely, functional analysis approach

Comment: @Kurt. W.X. Thank you for your replication. You are right. Now I correct it as following: for c) => a), please refer to Theorem 4.5.6 of  "V. I. Bogachev, Measure Theory, vol. 1, Springer-Verlag, (2007)". Th.4.5.6, p.269.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof for (a) $\Leftrightarrow$ (b) is correct in my opinion.

**(a) implies (c)**:

I do not know how to use the hint, but I think I found an alternative approach.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and a set $E\in B(\Bbb R)$ be given.
Let $\delta>0$ be given according to (a).
Then there is an open set $E_o\supset E$ such that
$\lambda(E_o\setminus E)\leq \delta$.
It follows that $\mu_n(E_o\setminus E)\leq \varepsilon$.

For open sets we know that we have $\mu(E_o)\leq \liminf \mu_n(E_o)$.
Thus we have
$$
\mu(E)\leq \mu(E_o) \leq \liminf \mu_n(E_o) \leq \liminf \mu_n(E) +\varepsilon.
$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, this implies
$\mu(E)\leq \liminf \mu_n(E)$
for all Borel sets $E$.
Applying this observation to the complement of $E$
will lead to
$\mu(E)=\lim \mu_n(E)$ after a couple of rearrangements.

**an observation regarding densities**:

If a measure $\nu$ has a density $g$, then
we have
$$
\forall \varepsilon>0 \exists \delta>0 \forall E\in B(\Bbb R):
\lambda(E)\leq\delta \implies \nu(E)=\int_E g(x)\mathrm dx \leq \varepsilon.
$$
In particular, this holds for $\mu$ and each single $\mu_n$.
One funny way to see this is to apply
"(b) implies (a)" to the constant sequence of measures $\nu$.
The difference between this property and the property from (a) is that the $\delta>0$
can be chosen independently of $n$.

Note that for finitely many $n$, one can always find a common $\delta>0$
by choosing the minimum of the respective $\delta$'s for each $n$.

It also follows that
$$
\label{equiv1}\tag{1}
\forall \varepsilon>0 \exists \delta>0 \exists n_0\in \Bbb N\forall n\geq n_0,
\forall E\in B(\Bbb R):
\lambda(E)\leq\delta \implies \int_E f_n(x)\mathrm dx \leq \varepsilon
$$
is equivalent to
$$
\label{equiv2}
\tag{2}
\forall \varepsilon>0 \exists \delta>0 \forall n\in\Bbb N,\forall E\in B(\Bbb R):
\lambda(E)\leq\delta \implies \mu_n(E)=\int_E f_n(x)\mathrm dx \leq \varepsilon.
$$

**(c) implies (a)**:

The weak convergence is probably clear for you.

Suppose that the rest of (a) is not true.
Then there exists $\varepsilon>0$
and a sequence $n_k\in\Bbb N,E_k\in B(\Bbb R)$ such that
$\lambda(E_k)\leq \hat\delta 2^{-k}$ and
$\mu_{n_k}(E_k)>\varepsilon$ hold.
Here, $\hat\delta>0$ is given such that
$
\forall E\in B(\Bbb R): \lambda(E)\leq\hat\delta \implies \mu(E)\leq \varepsilon/2
$.
Such an $\hat\delta$ exists by the *observation regarding density* above.

Suppose that $M:=\sup_k n_k<\infty$,
i.e. $n_k$ takes only finitely many values.
Then, by the *observation regarding density* above,
one could find $\delta>0$ independent of $k$ such that
$\lambda(E_k)\leq \delta$ implies $\mu_{n_k}(E_k)\leq\varepsilon$,
which would be a contradiction to our assumption.
Thus, we have $M:=\sup_k n_k=\infty$,
and we can (without loss of generality) assume that $n_k\to\infty$
as $k\to\infty$.

Alternatively, one can also obtain $n_k\to\infty$ by using the
negation of (\ref{equiv1}) instead of the negation of (\ref{equiv2})
as the assumption at the beginning of this proof.

We now define the set $E:=\cup_{k\in\Bbb N} E_k$.
Then we have $ \lambda(E)\leq\hat\delta $
and therefore
$$
\mu(E)\leq \varepsilon/2
< \varepsilon < \mu_{n_k}(E_k) \leq \mu_{n_k}(E).
$$
This is a contradiction to $\mu_{n}\to\mu(E)$.

**2.**:

I think this is true.

The above proof for (a) implies (c) does not rely on the assumption that
$\mu$ has a density.
Thus we know that
$\mu_n(E)\to \sigma(E)$ holds for all $E\in B(\Bbb R)$.

Since the $\mu_n$ measures are absolutely continuous,
it follows that $\sigma$ must be absolutely continuous, too.
Therefore $\sigma$ has a density.

**Remark regarding $\Bbb R^n$**:
As far as I can see, all these arguments for 1. and 2. also work for $\Bbb R^n$ instead
of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: a) $\implies$ c) you used Portmanteau theorem, is it possible to prove it (to simplify the reasoning) by taking $\mu$-continuous $E_0$ (that is $\mu(\overline{E_0}-Int(E_0))=0)$?

Comment: it's easier from the hint

Comment: @Kurt.W.X Maybe its possible. But the approximation of Borel sets with open sets is known (for the Lebesgue measure), and I do not know how this approximation would work for $\mu$-continuous $E_o$. Not sure if that would simplify things a lot.

Comment: Maybe regularity of $\lambda$ can help, there exist an open $O$ and a closed C such that $C \subset E \subset O$ such that $\lambda(O-C) \leq \delta$

Comment: After seeing the proof of a) $\implies$ c), 2) will be true. Indeed, Taking $\epsilon>0.$ there exist $\delta>0$ verifying a) taking $E \in B(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\lambda(E) \leq \delta.$ But for all $n \in \mathbb{N},\mu_n(E) \leq \epsilon,$ taking the limit $n \to +\infty,$ we obtain $\sigma(E) \leq \epsilon.$ So $\sigma$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: So we can conclude from this proof that for a sequence of probability measure  $(\mu_n)_n$ with densities $(f_n)_n.$ $(\mu_n)_n$ converges weakly to a probability measure $\mu$ and $$\lim_{k \to +\infty} \sup_n \mu_n(f_n>k)=0$$ if and only if $\mu$ has a probability density and $\forall E \in B(\mathbb{R}),\lim_n \mu_n(E)=\mu(E)$

Comment: 2 last questions: The theorem remains true considering density on $\mathbb{R}^d$? and in c) $\implies a)$ the subsequence $n_k$ can be increasing? since $$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0;\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall E \in B(\mathbb{R}),\lambda(E)\leq \delta\implies\int_Ef_n(x)dx \leq \epsilon$$ is equivalent to $$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0;\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N};\forall n \geq n_0, \forall E \in B(\mathbb{R}),\lambda(E)\leq \delta\implies\int_Ef_n(x)dx \leq \epsilon$$

Comment: @Kurt.W.X yes, this is the case. I elaborated a bit on this point for (c) implies (a). I also added the section on an observation regarding densities, whose results are probably not  surprising for you.

Comment: We can choose $n_k$ strictly increasing from this equivalence (how we construct a subsequence from convergence in probability to a.s convergence...)

Comment: @Kurt.W.X Yes, this is also possible! I added a sentence to mention that. I am not sure what this has to do with a.s. convergence, but I guess maybe you meant that as an analogy.